# How should I return the result from a service/use-case class

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core, design-patterns

In a REST API development using C# I've got a problem: If the service used by the controller returns an error, but the error depends on the business rules about something, how and where should I determine what status code to return in the HTTP response?

I mean, should that be the service responsability, or should the controller determine what status code to return based on the service result?

Nowadays at my team, we make the services return the status code and a message, as well as the payload, through a generic wrapper object from a class called Response. So when we wanna return, for example, a list of users, the service does something similar to

```cs
if (!users?.Any() ?? true)
    return new Response()
    {
        Message = "There are no users.",
        Status = HttpStatusCodes.Status204NoContent
    }

return new Response()
{
    Message = "Users retrieved successfully!",
    Status = HttpStatusCodes.Status200OK,    
    Data = users
}
```

However, this way doesn't look quite good to me even though that works, 'cause it's strange calling one method from ServiceA to ServiceB, given the fact an HTTP status code comes together unnecessarily sometimes.

One alternative for that is returning some Result object from the Service to the Controller, but do some data processing in a middleware converting the Result object to an effective Response object containing the status code.

So it could be something like this:

```cs
// Result object returned by services
public class Result<T>
{
    public string Message { get; }
    public ResultReason Reason { get; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public enum ResultReason
{
    BusinessRuleViolation, ItemNotFound, Success, InvalidParameter
}

// Response object returned by a middleware as an HTTP response body
public class Response<T>
{
    public string Message { get; }
    public int StatusCode { get; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public static class ResultMapper
{
    public static Response<T> ToResponse<T>(this Result<T> result)
    {
        return new Response()
        {
            Data = result.Data,
            Message = result.Message,
            StatusCode = result.Reason == ResultReason.BusinessRuleViolation ? 422
                : result.Reason == ResultReason.ItemNotFound ? 204
                : result.Reason == ResultReason.Success ? 200
                : result.Reason == ResultReason.InvalidParameter ? 400
        }
    }
}
```

Preferably, **I avoid using exceptions 'cause of performance concerns**.

Note: The example above doesn't necessarily work, I just wrote it for demonstration purposes

Comment: I don't think I just yet understand the issue. Are you talking about the transition point from Service back to Controller specifically? Wouldn't that API highly depend on the nature of that service?

Comment: @Fildor, the issue is that I don't think the service should be responsible for knowing which HTTP status code to return, 'cause that's not part of my domain. I'm just trying not to violate separation of concerns and single responsibility principles

Comment: In _that_ case (referring to your example) I don't see much use in creating a `ResultReason` enum that maps 1:1 to Http StatusCodes.

Comment: Me neither. That was much more like the first solution that came out of my mind

Comment: You did not ask for it, but have a look at [Ardalis: Result](https://github.com/ardalis/Result). Used it in a project and kind of liked it.

Comment: There's no real need for external classes. There's a standard for problem responses, RFC7807 that's already implemented by .NET Core in the ProblemDetails and ValidationProblemDetails classes. Validation errors automatically return a ValidationProblemDetails filled with the violations by field. You can use [return Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to return an ObjectResult containing a `ProblemDetails` payload

Comment: The Response class was already built-in, it's the ActionResult/IActionResult class. It's certainly not the *service's* job to decide what status to return (it's not a controller or API after all), but you can take advantage of the [IResult and Result types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-8.0#iresult-type) to make mapping of service to API results a *lot* easier. These were introduced in .NET 6 to make Minimal APIs easier.

Comment: BTW 204 is definitely *NOT* the correct status code to represent no users. 204 `indicates that a request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to navigate away from its current page.`. That's not the case here. The appropriate response would be a 200 with an empty body, something `return Ok(users)` or `return Results.Ok(user)` do well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos about the 204 status code, actually if there are no users, the request succeeded and the client doesn't necessarily need to navigate away. However I'm gonna consider starting to use 200 in this type of scenario, because it looks more reasonable in fact. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this result class in the service.

```
    public class Result<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public bool IsFailure { get; private set; }
    public T? Value { get; private set; }
    public string[]? Errors { get; private set; }

    private Result() { }

    public static Result<T> Success(T value) => new Result<T>() { IsSuccess = true, IsFailure = false, Value = value };
    public static Result<T> Failure(params string[] errors) => new Result<T>() { IsSuccess = false, IsFailure = true, Errors = errors };
}
```

The service layer could be used from some other function that is not http aware. So then in the outer layer you can decide what http code to return.

Comment: There's already a built-in ProblemDetails result type that implements the RFC7807 standard, which is already understood by clients and tooling. There's no need to create a new custom result type

Answer (score -1):

You can use problem details middleware from package [Middleware](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware). For more information about the problem details you can check microsoft documentation [Problem details service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#problem-details-service)

Basic idea is that you can have global custom exceptions in your domain layer, that you can map to business rules specific exceptions using problem details middleware.

So you will add this middleware to your pipeline in asp net core project. Additionally, then you can simply configure your exceptions like following (sample use case)

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomProblemDetails(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddProblemDetails(problemDetailsOptions =>
    {
        problemDetailsOptions.MapToStatusCodeWithErrorMessage<SomeCustomException>(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
    });

    return services;
}
private static void MapToStatusCodeWithErrorMessage<TException>(
    this ProblemDetailsOptions options,
    int statusCode,
    LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.Debug)
    where TException : Exception
{
    ExceptionsLogLevels.Add(typeof(TException).FullName!, logLevel);
    options.Map<TException>(
        exception =>
        {
            var problemDetails = StatusCodeProblemDetails.Create(statusCode);
            problemDetails.Detail = exception.Message;
            return problemDetails;
        });
}
```

You can then add this to your pipeline in ConfigureServices (if you are using old way) in minimal API, you will have to do it in program cs file.

```
services.AddCustomProblemDetails();
```

And inside Configure method

```
app.UseProblemDetails();
```

Now you can in your service layer basically just throw business domain specific custom exceptions and your controllers are lean.

The above example is based on the assumption that you will use the Middleware package i linked in this answer :)

**Updates based on comment from OP:**

If you would like to use result pattern for hot paths (which is also a recommended practice), then you can basically make sure that your services return always Result object and not any exception. However, in real world this is rare, you should have clarity in this manner so that you know when it makes sense to throw exception and when it makes sense to  use result pattern instead. I am saying this because method that throws must be well documented to let its users know that this is expected to throw some exceptions, and if you follow result pattern this is usually done to avoid exceptions.

Additionally, if you do not want to map errors to http codes in controller, you can use action filters to do this logic there. Another approach would be to do this mapping in a custom middleware, but for simplicity sake action filter is enough. A following example for return result object

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public T Data { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }

    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public static ApiResponse<T> SuccessResult(T data, int statusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK)
    { 
      return new ApiResponse<T> { Success = true, Data = data, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }

    public static ApiResponse<T> FailureResult(string error, int statusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)
    {
        return new ApiResponse<T> { Success = false, Error = error, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can do something like following, provided you return a result object from service layer

```
var result = YourServiceObject.ServiceMethodThatReturnsResultObject();
return Ok(ApiResponse<object>.SuccessResult(result));
```

There are lots of open source libraries available on github that implement result pattern and provide quite a lot of boiler plate already. One of such libraries is [FluentResults](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults)

Comment: That looks really cool. However, could you suggest something that doesn't include exceptions? I'm avoiding it specially because of performance issues

Comment: You don't need either exceptions or any extra package. `ProblemDetails` is a built-in result type used to return RFC7807 problem responses. Validation errors automatically return the derived ValidationProblemDetails content. In a controller you can use [return Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and specify any of the ProblemDetails you want

Comment: I am aware of that that is why i gave MS docs link as well in my answer. However, always better to give both options as some people may decide to go on with extra package route